# Inject SQL before Codeigniters $this->db->get() call

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

Here is what I try to do. I have a table with the following structure, that is supposed to hold translated values of other data in any other table

```
Translations
| Language id | translation | record_id | column_name | table_name |
====================================================================
| 1           | Hello       | 1         | test_column | test_table | 
| 2           | Aloha       | 1         | test_column | test_table |
| 1           | Test input  | 2         | test_column | test_table |
```

In my code I use in my views, I have a function that looks up this table, and returns the string in the language of the user. If the string is not translated in his language, the function returns the string in the default of the application (let's say with `ID = 1`)

It works fine, but I have to go through about 600 view files to apply this... I was wondering if it was possible to inject some SQL in my CodeIgniter models right before the `$this->db->get()` of the original record, that replaces the original column with the translated one.

Something like this:

```
$this->db->select('column_name, col_2, col_3');
// Injected SQL pseudocode:
// If RECORD EXISTS in table Translations where Language_id = 2 and record_id = 2 AND column_name = test_column AND table_name = test_table
// BEGIN
//     SELECT translations.translation as column_name
//     WHERE translations.table_name = test_table AND column_name = test_column AND record_id = 2
// END
// ELSE
// BEGIN
//     SELECT translations.translation as column_name
//     WHERE translations.table_name = test_table AND column_name = test_column AND record_id = 1
// END

$this->db->get('test_table');
```

Is this possible to be done somehow?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question well, but can't you just join the translation table to the query somehow?

Comment: I also need it to be conditional. "If row exist select from translation else keep the original column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're asking for doesn't really make sense. You "inject" by simply making different query first, then altering your second query based on the results.

the other option (perhaps better) would be to do all of this in a stored procedure, but it is still essentially the same, just with less connections & prolly quicker processing

Comment: In other words "if you want to rewrite your query, you have to rewrite your query".

Don't really know what I was thinking back then

Comment: exactly :-) we all get caught up in "magical methods" sometimes